# merge DataFrame by adding the data of the same index and leave the others unchanged

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge to dataFrame of pandas by adding data of the same index and leave the other unchanged, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame(index=['apple', 'banana', 'orange'], data=[1, 2, 5])
b = pd.DataFrame(index=['banana', 'pear'], data=[1, 1])
```

I want the result like(count the amount of the fruits):

```
c = pd.DataFrame(index=['apple', 'banana', 'bear', 'orange'], data=[1, 3, 1, 5])

#       0
#apple  1
#banana 3
#bear   1
#orange 5
```

Is there any easy function or way to realize this, thank you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `add` method with `fill_value` as 0:

```
a.add(b, fill_value=0)

#         0
#apple  1.0
#banana 3.0
#orange 5.0
#pear   1.0
```